# Sum Not showing Proper Results

Tags: sql

I got three tables named `EasyPaisa`, `TimePay`, and `Omni` having field `Profit` where `EasyPasia` got `(10,10)`, `Omni` got `(15,15)`, `TimePay` got `(20,20)`.

1. EasyPaisa  with the sum profit 20
2. Omni with the sum profit 30
3. TimePay with the sum profit 40

when I take out the profit with this query:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(EasyPaisa.Profit) AS Expr1, 
    Sum(Omni.Profit) AS Expr2, 
    Sum(TimePay.Profit) AS Expr3
FROM 
    EasyPaisa, 
    Omni, 
    TimePay;
```

it give me results double the actual result

1. EasyPaisa profit as 40
2. Omni Profit as 60
3. TimePay profit as 80

Comment: please show the table definition so we can help you.

Comment: When you use FROM tableA,tableB,tableC you are actually joining the tables on no common column to connect them by, this is causing your "joined" table to have all the combinations of the rows in your 3 tables, read about JOIN in SQL to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(Profit) FROM EasyPaisa) Expr1,
  (SELECT SUM(Profit) FROM Omni)      Expr2, 
  (SELECT SUM(Profit) FROM TimePay)   Expr3
```

Output:

```
| EXPR1 | EXPR2 | EXPR3 |
-------------------------
|    20 |    30 |    40 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/940e5/3)** demo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i really appreciate it,

I solved it the other way around I created three views each view contain one table sum and in the fourth view i added these three views now it shows me correct result,

Despite of 3 negative response I appreciate stackoverflow and my best regards to peter for his help,

thanks